# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' в Chrome & Opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль

Сделал в 2015 сайт. jQuery 2.2.4

И с октября, примерно, месяца (по словам владельца) перестал [этот сайт](https://karachun.com.ua) работать в Хроме и Опере.

Заглянул в консоль. А там - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" у ВСЕХ подгружаемых скриптов.

Ошибок в коде скриптов, думаю, нет, хотя бы потому, что даже убирая его весь, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" остается. Все скрипты в UTF-8 without BOM.

P.S. Поверьте, я уже два дня ломаю голову, и облазил все от СтэкОвкрфлоу до Хабра, и задаю здесь вопрос впервые.

P.P.S. FireFox работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Ваши линки на локальные сайту JS файлы возвращают не Javascript код а HTML

откройте например https://karachun.com.ua/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: Нет, это, типа, защита от открытия js в браузере.

Comment: @DenonBasf извините, а чем по вашему js файлы должны открываться и исполняться? вы попробуйте по этой ссылке ручками пройти защиту и у видете что сайт заработал, к сожалению браузер не умеет и не собирается проходить такую "защиту".
Кстати в FireFox тоже не работает, может у тех у кого работает уже прошли защиту?

Comment: Да, саппорт, наконец-то, раздуплился. Там ответили, что таким макаром они поставили "защиту от ботов". Просят подождать минут 15...

Comment: Ну у вас два варианта, 1) договориться с саппортом, чтобы отключили это для js файлов (такую "защиту" не один сайт не ставит на js файлы, реально бред) иначе у них просто не один сайт с ЛОКАЛЬНЫМ js не будет работать 2) забить на саппорт: уйти от локальных JS файлов и использовать CDN для получения всех нужных вам библиотек

Comment: СПАСИБО. Я уже сделал втык саппорту хостинга. Я еще вчера заподозрил нечто подобное. Но там заверили, что "не может быть!". Спасибо Вам еще раз! Пусть вопрос висит - может, кому-то поможет.